# mass attached to spring rotates in a horizontal circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, spring

So here is the question I have:

A mass of 2kg rotates at 1m/s in a horizontal circle on a table at the end of a spring with an elastic constant of 50N/m. If the original length of the spring is 2 meters, find the extension of the spring.

I have approached this question 2 ways:

### Approach#1: Using Hookes Law and Centripetal Force

I set Force of a spring = k*deltaX equal to centripetal force
where the radius is r = x + deltaX, where x = 2m (unstretched spring)

When you try to solve for deltaX you get a quadratic equation, see here:
deltaX^2 + 2*deltaX -0.04 = 0

When you solve this equation you get deltaX = 0.02 meter or 2cm.

### Approach #2

I decided to set the potential energy of the spring equal to the linear
kinetic energy = 0.5*m*v^2
When you set these equal, you get a simple quadratic equation of form:
deltaX^2 = 0.04m
Therefore you get deltaX = 0.2 meters or 20cm

---

I think I can't follow this second energy approach, because I guess I must use rotational kinetic energy. But using rotational kinetic energy is not within the scope of the study.
Only Conservation of Energy and Momentum ideas are to be used.

I am just wondering if I am correct with the first approach and if
there is a way to do this via Energy-Momentum ideas.

Hope someone can help.
Regards.

Comment: The first approach is fine. The second approach is wrong because there's no reason why the spring PE should be equal to the object KE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I would say your first approach is absolutely correct and will result in right answer if the calculations are done correctly (I have not done the calculations) but your second approach is faulty.

## Problem with second approach

In the second approach you have used the conservation of mechanical energy it seems. The problem is that conserving mechanical energy would mean that the kinetic energy loss is equal to the potential energy gain or vice versa but that isn't the case. Here both have increased due to some force which would have set the mass in motion.

## Possible Energy method approach

I don't think we can deal with this problem using the energy method as there seems no straight relation between kinetic and potential energy although the mechanical energy will remain conserved in the given motion(i.e. after the force is applied).

The energy approach would be a better option in cases such as

> What will be the new extension in the spring if the Mass(M) now collides with another mass(m) and stick to it and both start doing the circular motion.
>
> What will be the new extension if the mass splits up into two equal halves out of which one keeps on doing the circular motion while the other executes a linear motion.

Comment: Hi Pranav, Thanks for your response. Really appreciate it. Thanks for the great details, you really opened up all the possible cases that may result.